# How to replace some characters after a specific character to another specific character in one big sql line in notepad++

Tags: sql, search, replace, notepad++

I have a big sql file with thousand user something like this:

```
('someone1@mydomain.com','{SSHA512}JWHCqHzazH2vGneLPfhMKkoAamzvxdNCWYOlhZ+uDx36jHdoMXwQmbEemvUMn7ZG6c9+22noXjjb2hAb99/5A/slscDJPKav','','en_US','maildir','Maildir','/home/vmail','vmail1','mydomain.com/someone1/',0,'mydomain.com','','','normal','',0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,NULL,'1970-01-01 01:01:01',0,'',NULL,NULL,'2020-03-19 13:15:58','2015-08-03 06:11:53','2020-03-19 13:15:58','9999-12-31 00:00:00',1'someone1'),
('someone2@mydomain.com','{SSHA512}UoMeyocmdC2DxM0S7B4WFdjnCNuvkngzzLus33h9nugKVlvdhlcboKmMDDuAkCHEyLBUgf8DicKWFPJVS7EOF/ytv27MQ3Ch','','en_US','maildir','Maildir','/home/vmail','vmail1','mydomain.com/someone2/',0,'mydomain.com','','','normal','',0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,NULL,'1970-01-01 01:01:01',0,'',NULL,NULL,'2015-12-17 12:27:35','2015-08-03 06:44:10','2021-06-08 06:55:33','9999-12-31 00:00:00',1'someone2'),
('someone3@mydomain.com','{SSHA512}A6ToCf4OfP3XNEU9ngEmGN/LDquH9+s9Qxme3SoJaDyVvxiWpnwwTiAALSdnmhIxDB2VQK0zhdF+jP8ARvh0N3IDL0Xv/KmL','','en_US','maildir','Maildir','/home/vmail','vmail1','mydomain.com/someone3/',0,'mydomain.com','','','normal','',0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,NULL,'1970-01-01 01:01:01',0,'',NULL,NULL,'2018-04-03 12:31:09','2015-08-03 06:50:01','2018-04-03 12:31:18','9999-12-31 00:00:00',1'someone3'),
('someone4@mydomain.com','{SSHA512}t7/JbUPQ+rtKeRTgWRH6KlETr2JsqYORBOZouzOzs4Wo6YfHYLoy0m+U4kZXk+AeNgMep2hGZSodPZdK2l2bn9MhOKHOuF/L','','en_US','maildir','Maildir','/home/vmail','vmail1','mydomain.com/someone4/',0,'mydomain.com','','','normal',''0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,NULL,'1970-01-01 01:01:01',0,'',NULL,NULL,'2020-03-18 07:48:26','2016-11-14 06:59:04','2021-06-08 05:54:28',9999-12-31 00:00:00',1'someone4')
```

And now I need to delete the last word ('someone1' , 'someone2' , 'someone3' , 'someone4') for every user which adjoining to 1. It will be looks like

```
....9999-12-31 00:00:00',1)
```

not like in original

```
....9999-12-31 00:00:00',1'someone1')
....9999-12-31 00:00:00',1'someone2')
```

etc

But don't forget they are not in different lines. All this is in one big line and this makes me to ask you help. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that (from your examples) the rows do not contain any parentheses except their start and end characters. So you can search for one quotation mark `'`, and a number of letters and/or digits, and one quotation mark `'`, and than `)`.

To do this;

- Open Replace window in Notepad++ by using `ctrl+h` shortcut
- From Search Mode section select Reqular expression
- Write `'[a-zA-Z0-9]*?[-,_,.]*?[a-zA-Z0-9]*?[-,_,.]*?[a-zA-Z0-9]*?[-,_,.]*?[a-zA-Z0-9]*?'\)` to Find what box
- Write `'\)` to Replace with box
- Click Replace All button.

This works if user names consist of letters or digits and `_`, `-`, `.` at most 3 times.

Be Sure that you have a copy of original file as a backup. And also be aware of that  the regular expression that we use may find unrelated parts if any row contains closing parentheses except end of it.

Comment: This is not bad, but usernames contains dot or _ or - symbols and '[a-zA-Z0-9]*?'\) this is not works me. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Does a user name contain that symbols more than one?

Comment: I update my answer to handle usernames that contains at most 3 symbols.

Comment: no in 99% situations I have usernames with only "-", "_" and "." this symbols.

Comment: have a look at my updated answer and you can extend that regex to handle other symbols.